# How to enforce specific package version on sub-dependency for netstandard library

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dependencies, .net-standard-2.0

I am building a netstandard2.0, with a series of sub-dependencies, including Azure.Data.Tables. I have found that Azure.Data.Tables on >=12.3.0 is not compatible with 2.2 projects, but version 12.0.0 is (or at least it doesn't crash my .Net Core 2.2 application).

Based on these premises the resolution was simple: put version 12.0.0 in the netstandard library dependencies. There's only one problem, that when I install this library using Visual Studio into my Net Core 2.2 project I get that visual studio decides to install 12.3.0.

I have checked documentation around enforcing certain versions using the allowed wildcards(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#version-ranges-and-wildcards), such as:

`<PackageReference Include="Azure.Data.Tables" Version="[12.0.0]" />`
Which produces this package description just before pressing "install".
[image]

But it doens't seem to work, Visual Studio simply carries on with the 12.3.0 installation.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out Visual Studio was just using the nuget cache for my locally generated packages. If I either changed the version of the packaged package then the sub-dependencies would change. As well, another way of getting the precise package would be to clear nuget's cache locally: `nuget locals all -clear`.